# Namespace, argparse, and usage

Tags: python, namespaces, argparse

This is really a few questions:

1. Is there a reason argparse uses a namespace instead of a dictionary?
2. Assuming I have a class with `__init__(self, init_method, *args)`. The `init_method` parameter tells the init_function which way I want to initialize the class, while `arg` parameter gives all the arguments neccesary for the init. The arguments may be different for different methods. Should I use a dictionary, or a namespace?
3. Assuming that I use a namespace, how do I pass the namespace to `__init__()`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. The designers of `arparse` apparently felt it would be more convenient to access arguments as

   ```
   args.arg_name
   ```

   rather than

   ```
   args["arg_name"]
   ```

   This might be a matter of taste, though.  I would have happily gone with the dictionary, especially given the fact that there is no `Namespace` class in the standard library, except for the one in `argparse`.
2. Use a dictionary.
3. If you really want a namespace here, you can use `init_function(**args.__dict__)`…but I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 68):

It is easy to convert a *Namespace* into a dictionary using [vars()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#vars):

```
>>> vars(args)
```

Comment: I'm using this so I can have a module which is either a stand-alone utility or a function. Getting args from argparse, I can call:        my_func(**vars(parser.args)),         as long as I make my parameter names match the names I define in argparse